# Advanced MySQL query issue with non-unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that are set up like so:

```
Quotes Table                        Stores Table    
id  store_id    date_submitted      store_number    code
1   15          1/29/13 23:13       15          ANT
2   16          1/30/13 7:47        16          MAT

Leads Table 
code    user_name
MAT         User1
ANT         User2
```

What I want to be able to do is have the query return all the values in the quotes table, and then the code values from the Stores table, and the user_name from the leads table. I would like it to look something like this:

```
id  store_id    date_submitted  code    user_name
1   15          1/29/13 23:13   ANT User2
2   16          1/30/13 7:47    MAT User1
```

I have the following query that I wrote:

```
SELECT id, store_id, date_submitted, code, user_name FROM quotes q, stores s, leads l WHERE CONCAT('%', q.store_id, '%') LIKE CONCAT('%', s.store_number, '%') AND s.code=l.code AND date_submitted > "2013-01-01 00:00:00" AND date_submitted < "2013-01-31 23:59:59" GROUP BY q.id
```

The problem I'm running into, is the database isn't matching the code to the correct store_id.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I have looked at a couple of SO posts, and googled for it to no avail.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, why are you using wildcards (`%`) to join `store_id` with `store_number`?, can't you use an exact match?. Also, just for clarity, you should use explicit `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT id, store_id, date_submitted, code, user_name 
FROM quotes q
INNER JOIN stores s
    ON q.store_id = s.store_number
INNER JOIN leads l 
    ON s.code=l.code 
WHERE date_submitted > "2013-01-01 00:00:00" 
AND date_submitted < "2013-01-31 23:59:59" 
GROUP BY q.id
```

Comment: Thanks, the reason I was using the (%) was because some store id's had leading zeros, but i ended up using TRIM instead.